# How to get ESRI Addin to read the System.ServiceModel configuration?

Tags: arcmap, .net, add-in, services

I have a complex set of add-in's that we need to run in ArcMap, ArcServer, and ArcGIS Explorer for Desktop.  We are experimenting with changing from the old Web Reference service connection to a WCF Service Reference connection.

When I try to create the client it cannot find the configuration settings to create the client.  When I add just the URI to the embedded Settings.settings file, and create an EndpointAddress and Binding object to pass to the client, I get a client but my first attempt to access the server fails.

So how do I access the WCF service configuration data from inside an ArcMap Addin?

Comment: This sounds like two different questions to me. 1) How to read configuration and 2) How to access a WCF service. I would suggest tackling one at a time.

Comment: I have the how, but I cannot execute the how because the client wants to load it's data from application configuration data.  I modified the question to clarify the results.

Comment: How do you know it cannot find the configuration settings? Have you tried debugging the add-in at the point where the configuration settings are read to see what value if any is being read? If you're just trying to read a string out of the embedded Settings.settings file, `Properties.Settings.Default.<yourSettingName>` should work.

Comment: I know it cannot get the settings because WCF throws an exception saying that the configuration cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

I spent the better part of the day trying to figure this out.

I found an answer on geonet
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/98429

Simply, it isn't seeing the app.config.

You need to setup all the bindings manually.

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =HttpClientCredentialType.None;

EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("SERVICEENDPOINT");
Service1Client client = new Service1Client(binding, remoteAddress);
```

You may find an issue with a 415 error and encoding.  I found this an issue too.
I ended up using:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text

EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("SERVICEENDPOINT");
Service1Client client = new Service1Client(binding, remoteAddress);

'call what ever you need here'
```

After I did this it worked.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found a current approach to this by adding WCF data to the Arcmap.exe.config file.  This, however is just a workaround.  I would prefer WCF go after an external config.

Answer (score 0):

The second answer of KevonFredrico worked well for me. With the BasicHttpBinding object you can indicate extra properties that are specified in your app.config like TransferMode or SendTimeout:

```
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,10,0); //10 minutes
```